# Store commonly used microservice entities in Hazelcast cache?

Tags: microservices, hazelcast

We have User and Order microservices. We also have many other, but User and Order are frequently used between them.

Does it make sense to cache the User and Order entities in Hazelcast distributed cache for others usage (to improve latency between microservices), or should I cache only on microservice level and REST call from other microservice ?

If Cache is ok for this, how can I disable cache updates from microservices that dont own these entities ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a good question and the answer is: "it depends". By using a cache, you're making a trade-off. Between correctness (or more precisely freshness) of data, and speed to get it, you favor speed. You actually prefer stale data now instead of fresh data later.

As you can see, it's hard to say which is better, because it depends a lot on your context.

Note that by using Hazelcast, you can also refresh the cache so that stale is not as great a problem as it could be. There are many ways to do that, one among them are Jet jobs. The best way is likewise and unfortunately context-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this is more of a design decision. It largely depends on the level of isolation you choose for microservices. You can choose to run a single cluster for all your microservices, with full access control where services can be allowed to access caches based on their authorization levels that you can define. So for example, create 2 caches - User and Order, make them accessible to User_ms (ms = micro-service) and Order_ms, and limit access to others.

For other micro-services to access the cluster, either for User and Order caches or other caches in the same cluster, you can control and define their level of access. See here in detail: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12.5/manual/html-single/index.html#security

You can also cache data on microservice level by configuring NearCache, where an update on the master data immediately invalidates data in NearCache - all this happens and managed internally by Hazelcast.

Alternatively, in full isolation mode, you can run micro-clusters at micro-service level - dedicated cluster for each micro-service that is not shared by other services.